# Javascript form validating and prevent submission

Tags: javascript

How can I prevent submision if in my text field are entered  just specific characters <>{} and not all of special characters? I'm losing my mind :/

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Please show us what you got so far and also, here you got lots of examples. You need to search for Regex(regular expression)  https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer as you didn't post any sample code. I can only point you to this article https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing which explain how events bubbling works. A solution will be to use `event.stopPropagation()` in case the validation doesn't pass.

Here an working ex:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function validateForm() {
      const regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]+$');
      const input = document.forms['someForm']['somename'].value;
      if (regex.test(input)) {
        console.log("true");
      } else {
        console.log("false");
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <form name="someForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="somename">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: An example of what I did so far: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["someForm"]["somename"].value;
    if (x == "<",”>”,”{“,”}”) {
        alert("Wrong character!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="someForm"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="somename">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
'

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I was looking for. I tried different solutions but I couldn't find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, will appreciate if you can accept it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for regex expression. Let me know if it's helpful

```
$(":input").each(function() {
  var input = $(this).val();
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
  if(regex.test(input)) {
    alert("true");
  } else {
    alert("false");
    return false;
  }
})
```

Comment: Here is the example of my code, problem is that whatever I type in form field returns false, not just the characters that I wanted to prevent. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["someForm"]["somename"].value;
    if (x == "<",”>”,”{“,”}”) {
        alert("Wrong character!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="someForm"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="somename">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>